# group by and sum using linq

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

```
Id | Value

1    50
2    60
3    80
3    50
2    20
1    60
1   100
```

I would like to calculate using linq query the total for every id. I know I have to use the `group by` statement as same in sql:

```
select id, sum(Value)
from MyTable
group by id
```

but how can I achieve this using linq or lambda?

Comment: @nozzleman I saw that question, but I do really want a simple and concrete example

Comment: you didn't ask as simple and concrete question (e.g.: c# code: List, DataSet, other format? etc.) so it is hard to answer properly.

Comment: So, my 'little' table with 2 columns, for you it isn't a concrete example? Nice

Comment: No need to get mad. I just wanted to point out, that the code you need would look different if you had the data already in a `List` of some `class`. Thats not obvious. All we know is that there is data in a database. There are many ways of tackling the issue. All depend on other circumstances. If you expect people to put effort into anwers, you are expected o provide all the information they need to provide a satisfactory answer. i really didn't mean to offend, i just marked another answer adressing the exact problem in a understandable way.

Comment: Sorry, my fault. I just wanted a simple and concrete example for a simple table using group by and sum. I think I'll delete the question as it is a duplicate of another one.

Comment: You could of course delete or vote to close your own question, if you feel the duplicate answers your question - which I doubt, at least if you´re unfamiliar with Linq.

Comment: You may also accept one of the answers if they solve your issue. It was just my opinion. Again: I didn't want to anger ;)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
var list;
// manipulate list from your table;

list
  .GroupBy(t=>t.Id)
  .Select(t=>new { ID= t.Key , Value= t.Sum(u=>u.Value)}).ToList
```

Answer (score 2):

Did not test, but should work:

```
from entry in MyTable
group entry by entry.Id into g
select new { Id = g.Key, Sum = g.Sum(e => e.Value) };
```

Or, if you prefer a method chaining syntax:

```
MyTable.GroupBy(entry => entry.Id).Select(g => new { Id = g.Key, Sum = g.Sum(e => e.Value) });
```

Comment: "group by" or group entry by ?

Comment: @FlorinM. Yes, the correct syntax is `group entry by entry.Id into g`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
var results = from p in tables
              group by p.Id into g
              select new { Id = g.Key, Value = g.Sum(item=>item.Value) };
```