# C# Sum Object List on specific property

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq

I'm currently developing an ASP.NET app where I need to display several charts based on data I receive from a database. I receive them as a list of objects, which looks like this for example:

```
{ 
    { name: "A", val: 20 }, 
    { name: "A", val: 10 }, 
    { name: "B", val: 6 }, 
    { name: "C", val: 1 }, 
    { name: "C", val: 20 } 
}
```

I want to transform this list, the target list should look like this:

```
{ { name: "A", val: 30 } { name: "B", val: 6 }, { name: "C", val: 21 } }
```

I want all objects with name "A" to be "merged together" into one object, where val now is the sum of all values of the single objects. Currently I'm using a foor loop and a new List, which I loop through evvery time to achieve this, but I think this is very inefficient. There is probably some LINQ option to do this but I haven't found anything. How can I optimize this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is ***json*** , is that what you are working with? Or are these C# classes you have used the wrong syntax for ?

Comment: If the later, `List.GroupBy(x => x.name ).Select( x => new { name = x.Key, val = x.Sum()});`

Comment: Oh yeah I wrote it down in JSON but they are indeed objects in the code

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Linq: GroupBy, Sum and Count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16522645/linq-groupby-sum-and-count)

Comment: related : [group by and sum using linq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41846262/group-by-and-sum-using-linq)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use a [`GroupBy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupby?view=netcore-3.1) and project the results

> Groups the elements of a sequence.

**Example**

```
var results = List.GroupBy(x => x.name)
                  .Select( x => new { name = x.Key, val = x.Sum(x => x.val) });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`.GroupBy()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupby?view=netcore-3.1) to group list of object based on `Name` property and then use [`.Sum()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.sum?view=netcore-3.1) to calculate sum of all values of `Val` property.

```
var groupResult = ListOfObject
    .GroupBy(x => x.Name)
    .Select(y => new
            {
                Name= y.Key,
                Val = y.Sum(s => s.Val)
            });
```

[.Net Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/DforgH)

Answer (score 1):

You can also sum it on database side
https://www.w3resource.com/sql/aggregate-functions/sum-with-group-by.php

Comment: Interesting approach but sadly this wouldn't be a good idea with my current project structure, thanks for the answer nevertheless!