# Return async task list using c#

Tags: c#, linq, c#-6.0

I have following classes and enum:

```cs
public class StatusCount
{
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public int Count { get; set; }
}

public enum myEnum {
    A,
    B,
    C
}

public async Task<List<StatusCount>> GetStatusCount()
{
    var listOfEnums = System.Enum.GetValues(typeof(myEnum)).Cast<myEnum>().ToList();//A,B,C
    var query1 =_dbcontext.Table1.Include().Where().Count();//10
    var query2 =_dbcontext.Table2.Include().Where().Count();//5
    var query2 =_dbcontext.Table3.Include().Where().Count();//15

    return ???
}
```

Output I want from `GetStatusCount` method is like below and need to return list to controller. Not sure how to map/send query1 `count` value with status 'A' and so on.

```json
[
    {
        status:A
        count: 10
    },
    {
        status:B
        count: 5
    },
    {
        status:C
        count: 15
    }
]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [group by and sum using linq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41846262/group-by-and-sum-using-linq)

Comment: I have separate queries and a list and need to send query1 count and list first value and so on to the controller.

Comment: `return new List<StatusCount>(){ new StatusCount(){ Status = "A", Count = query1 }, new StatusCount(){ Status = "B", Count = query2 }, new StatusCount(){ Status = "C", Count = query3 } } `?

Comment: It is really bad question.  We cannot understand output. Includes with Count have no sense and there are not classes definition.

Comment: How does the `myEnum` value relate to `Table1` etc? And those `Include()` and `Where()` calls make no sense.

Comment: Did you learn nothing about how to ask a good question from all the guidance I gave you in your other question yesterday?

Answer (score 0):

Probably you need here grouping by constant. It will allow to use `Count` and return `IQueryable`

```cs
public async Task<List<StatusCount>> GetStatusCount()
{
    var query1 = _dbcontext.Table1.Where(...).GroupBy(x => 1).Select(x => new StatusCount{ Status = "A", Count = g.Count() });
    var query2 = _dbcontext.Table2.Where(...).GroupBy(x => 1).Select(x => new StatusCount{ Status = "B", Count = g.Count() });
    var query3 = _dbcontext.Table3.Where(...).GroupBy(x => 1).Select(x => new StatusCount{ Status = "C", Count = g.Count() });

    return query1.Concat(query2).Concat(query3).ToListAsync();
}
```